# Ubuntu crashed unexpectedly when browsing

Tags: boot, live-cd, ext4

How can I boot to Live CD and then access Ext4 partitions.

Comment: Use the Ubuntu CD and choose try Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the Ubuntu Live CD, go find another computer, download the image and burn it on a CD/DVD.

When you've done that, or if you already have the live CD, make sure your BIOS is set to boot from CD/DVD before booting from HD.

When your pc is off, put in the Ubuntu Live CD, close the drive and startup your pc. When you are asked, choose "run live CD" and wait until you see the desktop. In the Live session, you can access any HD, USB drive, etc... you want. If you want, you can reinstall the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: You may want to expand this to include information about how to mount volumes (at least in Nautilus) and how to bypass permissions (since files and folders not viewable by UID 999 won't be readable by the `ubuntu` user on the live CD).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea. I had to do it once, on my personal laptop. I don't remember having had trouble mounting the harddisk in Nautilus (just doubleclick it?) or accessing files (use sudo password?). I'm sorry, I'm just a self-thaught amateur ubuntuist, nothing fancy; my expertise is in a totally different field (not even related to ITC...)